# What values to pass in react-chartjs

Tags: react-chartjs

Was using react-chartjs from [link](https://github.com/reactjs/react-chartjs) . Examples are given fine with demos, but the `data` and `options` that need to pass along is not mentioned anywhere. Was using flotjs pie graph and sending the same data and options as below, but it doesn't seem to work ? Is there any `css/less` need to be added so that graph should come fine or is there any problem with the input data ?

```
var chartData=[   {label: "Series 0",data: 1},
                  {label: "Series 1",data: 3},
                  {label: "Series 2",data: 9},
                  {label: "Series 3",data: 20}
              ];

var chartOptions={ series: { pie: { show: true } }, 
                   grid  : { hoverable: true }, 
                  tooltip: true,
              tooltipOpts: { content: "%p.0%, %s", shifts: {x: 20,y: 0},                   
                             defaultTheme: false }};

<PieChart data={chartData} options={chartOptions} width="600" height="250"/>
```

Also, importing chart.js and React in the existing component. Can anybody please tell whether `chartData` and `chartOptions` is correct ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using the master branch of **react-chartjs**, their documentation links to Chart.js V2.

However, the library uses Chart.js V 1.1.1. The documentation can be found here [Chart.js documentation V 1.1.1](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/tree/v1.1.1/docs).

Answer (score 0):

After some under the hood debugging I figured out that we should use for chartData
not data property, but value:

```
var chartData=[{label: "Series 0",value: 1},
               {label: "Series 1",value: 3},
               {label: "Series 2",value: 9},
               {label: "Series 3",value: 20}];
```